# "EACH" Keyword isn't returning correct result in "GROUP EACH BY"

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have had an issue over the last month with BigQuery and the use of the keyword "EACH".  I have many reports that rely on some very specific and refined queries on Google Analytics Data that I have not been able to update due to this issue.  I have not changed my query in any way, but one day the results started appearing as "0" rather than the actual number.

I would love to know if there was a recent production change in BigQuery that might have caused this or if I am doing something wrong.  I would really love a resolution on this, it has been happening for a while and really effecting the reporting needs that we have grown to rely on.  Below are some additional details of my issue:

Job ID that produces that bad result: **jjldtlwOeW2zyxvi7SViTxsDJzA**

Bug posted: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=195

**-- Query that doesn't produce the correct result**

```
select
    date(date) as date
    ,sum(case when hits.type = "page" then 1 else 0 end) as pageviews
    ,count(distinct (case when hits.type = "page" then concat(fullvisitorid, string(visitid), hits.page.pagepath) end), 1000000) as unique_pageviews

from
    table_date_range([XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_], timestamp('2014-10-06'), timestamp('2014-10-06'))

group each by
    date

ignore case;
```

**-- Query that does work (But cant handle Large amount of data):**

```
select
    date(date) as date
    ,sum(case when hits.type = "page" then 1 else 0 end) as pageviews
    ,count(distinct (case when hits.type = "page" then concat(fullvisitorid, string(visitid), hits.page.pagepath) end), 1000000) as unique_pageviews

from
    table_date_range([XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_], timestamp('2014-10-06'), timestamp('2014-10-06'))

group by
    date

ignore case;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've found a bug in `IGNORE CASE` and `GROUP EACH BY`.

I was able to reproduce on my own set of analytics data.  We'll investigate further to determine a root cause.  In the meantime, a workaround is to remove `IGNORE CASE` from your query and make each of your  equality checks case-insensitive using `LOWER` as follows:

```
select
    date
    ,sum(case when lower(hits.type) = "page" then 1 else 0 end) as pageviews
    ,count(distinct (case when lower(hits.type) = "page" then concat(fullvisitorid, string(visitid), hits.page.pagepath) end), 1000000) as unique_pageviews

from
    table_date_range([XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_], timestamp('2014-10-06'), timestamp('2014-10-06'))

group each by
    date;
```

Comment: Awesome!  That actually went though my mind yesterday but I ran out of time to give it a try.  This is a great interim solution, but very tedious to add to some of my queries that are 100s of lines long.

Comment: We've determined a root cause and submitted a fix.  The fix should be deployed after the holidays, probably in January.